# Get Mysql summarised data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have  MYsql table data in following manner.

```
user-id |salecount |datetime

2        40       2014-04-11 23:53:58

2        30       2014-04-11 23:32:14

2        30       2014-04-12 23:32:14

4        56       2014-04-11 22:32:14

4        70       2014-04-12 20:32:14

4        10       2014-04-12 20:32:14
```

I want output like date wise user total.

For above input i want output.

```
user-id |saletotal |date

2       70          2014-04-11

2       30          2014-04-12

4       56          2014-04-11

4       80          2014-04-12
```

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.user_id, SUM(a.salecount), DATE(a.datetime)
FROM tableA a 
GROUP BY a.user_id, DATE(a.datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT user_id,SUM(salecount),DATE(DATETIME) FROM tablename1 
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(DATETIME)
```